# Html + CSS div display error

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

N.B: am using bootstrap for just columns.
and this is custom page in my WordPress website.
the image of problem:
[screen shoot for problem and what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuHJk.png)

this is my code html:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://www.cheapwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/blog-481x230.jpg" alt="blog service">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Blog services</h3>
        <p>We can create for you professional blog, or edit  your blog, or other Services for it </p>
        <p><a href="#" class="click" role="click">Check Now</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://www.cheapwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ForumLogo_FINAL_red.jpg" alt="Forum services">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Forum services</h3>
        <p>We can create for you any type fo forums, or edit , or other Services for it </p>
        <p><a href="#" class="click" role="click">Check Now</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://www.cheapwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/landing-page-blog-marketeamos.jpg" alt="Landing page services">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Landing page services</h3>
        <p>Landing page is our mession Contact us here </p>
        <p><a href="#" class="click" role="click">Check Now</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://www.cheapwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/564-315px.png" alt="Web hosting services help">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Web hosting services help</h3>
        <p>We can help you to choose best hosting ever for your need</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="click" role="click">Check Now</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://www.cheapwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/empresas-de-hospedagem-web-480x240.jpg" alt="burchase web hosting or domain">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>burchase web hosting or domain</h3>
        <p>We can buy for You Good Hosting as your budget</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="click" role="click">Check Now</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is css code:

```
.thumbnail{
  border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.click {
    background-color: #44ccf2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.click:hover {
    background-color: #2f3c4e;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

please help me i can't fix without you 
thanks

Comment: I have taken a look at all code given, this is not your issue. there is something in your css messing the rest up

Answer (score 0):

you can change `.thumbnail` from `display: block` to display: `inline-block` and remove the `float: left`. Also, you will need to remove the `float` from the`.col`classes and change to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: If you want to use less code you can have just one column and set a width and display:inline-block to your thumbnail images...

Comment: not working :( see image after add you instrodaction : http://i.imgur.com/qB7ZaFK.png

Comment: It is, sort of. You will also need to set the vertical-align of the thumbnail to top, and fiddle with the width of the thumbnail to fit 3 in a column.

Comment: having had a look at your code, I suggest to have only one column and set width to the thumbnail img to 30% and add some margin

Comment: Probably best to put your code in a fiddle too in order for us to help you better

Comment: ok my code html: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhw0cf5edbp7zjc/Services.html?dl=0

my code css:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ocbkqx53iwbbmb/div.css?dl=0

Comment: The reason that the images aren't going to the left is that they're floating and so are the cols. So all you need is to remove the float from either the bootstrap cols and/or the images. display: inline-block will solve this issue, but you will need to set/update the widths of your columns and/or images. Play around with these settings and let me know if you will be able to get this working for you.

Comment: am fix the problem with this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ocbkqx53iwbbmb/div.css?dl=0

just add the height:
 height: 400px;

Answer (score 0):

try this, remove float left and replaced display inline-block to flex.

```
.thumbnail{
  border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
```